# Implement custom Send mail button on outlook addin usning office-js

Tags: office-js, sendmail, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am implementing my first Outlook Add-in using office-js and I have made an inline editor (inside task pane) that is going to be used to reply to the current/active mail. I have found workarounds to retrieve sender's email address, email's subject, and body and now I want to implement a custom button that will actually Send the mail. Actually, replicate outlook's native "Send" action. Is it possible? I will need to implement on Outlook online App. I am not interested in DeskTop App.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the feature: sending mail via add-in, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. 
Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins